# Spring Boot Could not find or load main class error in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

My spring boot project extends another parent project, which isn't a spring boot project. Here is what my pom looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Microservice</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.abc.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <javasource.skip>false</javasource.skip>

        <owasp.skip>true</owasp.skip>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tracing Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Suppression file for checkstyle <plugin> <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId> 
                    <configuration> <suppressionsLocation>./checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation> 
                    </configuration> </plugin> -->

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <!-- Use supression file for checkstyle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <suppressionsLocation>./checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>none</parallel>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                    <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                    <jvm>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/java</jvm>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

mvn clean install works fine, but when viewed through Eclipse, only thing generated in the target directory is the suppression related files. When I right click on the class with main and try to run, I get the "Error:Could not find or load main class" error message.

Running mvn org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:run from the project root gives me "Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property" error message. I've tried almost all the recommended solutions, but none seem to work for me. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!